# ViewPager re-instantiates items out of order after screen rotation

Tags: android, user-interface, android-fragments, android-viewpager, android-pageradapter

I'm using a `ViewPager` that contains several ListViews, with code similar to that in the answer for [Infinite ViewPager](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7440012/infinite-viewpager). The idea is to have something like the day view for the Google Calendar app (whose source seems to be unavailable; only the default calendar app's is but it uses a `ViewSwitcher`) - I want to make it seem like the user can swipe infinitely left and right, but there are actually only 3 items in the `ViewPager`, and when the user hits page 0 or 2, we set 1 as the current page and update accordingly.

Now, this all works. However, strangely, when the phone is rotated and the activity is rebuilt (I'm avoiding using `configChanges` for now), the pages in the app are instantiated again, but out of order. Instead of 0->1->2, the order is 1->0->2, and this screws up the order of the pages in the app.

**My Fragment, in `onActivityCreated()`:**

```
mPagerAdapter = new ContinuousPagerAdapter(R.layout.my_listview, this);

// set the adapter
mViewPager = (ViewPager) getView().findViewById(R.id.agendaViewPager);
mViewPager.setOffscreenPageLimit(3);
mViewPager.setOnPageChangeListener(this);
mViewPager.setAdapter(mPagerAdapter);
mViewPager.setSaveEnabled(false);
// ...
mViewPager.setCurrentItem(1, false);
loadData();
```

**The Pager Adapter:**

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.os.Parcelable;
import android.support.v4.view.PagerAdapter;
import android.support.v4.view.ViewPager;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;

public class ContinuousPagerAdapter extends PagerAdapter {

    OnPageInstantiatedListener pListener;
    ViewPager container;
    int childLayoutResId;

    @SuppressWarnings("unused")
    private ContinuousPagerAdapter() {
    }

    /**
     * @param childLayoutResId Layout resource ID of the children to be inflated
     */
    public ContinuousPagerAdapter(int childLayoutResId, OnPageInstantiatedListener pListener) {
        this.childLayoutResId = childLayoutResId;
        this.pListener = pListener;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return 3;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isViewFromObject(View view, Object object) {
        return view == object;
    }

    @Override
    public Object instantiateItem(View container, int position) {
        this.container = (ViewPager) container;

        // inflate a new child view
        LayoutInflater li = (LayoutInflater) container.getContext().getSystemService(
                Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        View childView = li.inflate(childLayoutResId, null, false);

        // add it to the view pager and return
        int count = this.container.getChildCount();
        int actualPos = count > position ? position : count;
        this.container.addView(childView, actualPos);
        pListener.onPageInstantiated(actualPos); // sometimes use 0 instead of actualPos, with different but still inconsistent results
        return childView;
    }

    @Override
    public void destroyItem(View container, int position, Object object) {
        ((ViewPager) container).removeViewAt(position);
    }

    public static interface OnPageInstantiatedListener {
        public void onPageInstantiated(int position);
    }

    /**
     * Needed to ensure all the items are instantiated
     */
    @Override
    public int getItemPosition(Object object) {
        return POSITION_NONE;
    }

    @Override
    public Parcelable saveState() {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public void restoreState(Parcelable state, ClassLoader loader) {
    }

    @Override
    public void finishUpdate(View container) {
    }
}
```

I don't understand why the pages are instantiated in the 1->0->2 order after rotation. I'm not saving state either. Any insights into this would be helpful.

Comment: Can you post the rest of your Fragment code?

Comment: The other code isn't really relevant to this issue; however I figured it out already.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After meticulously debugging the app and looking through the `ViewPager` source, I found the problem.

The first time the app starts and `mViewPager.setAdapter(mPagerAdapter)` is called, the pages are instantly initiated and the app works as it should. However, when the phone is rotated, calling `setAdapter()` postpones instantiating the pages because `getWindowToken()` returns null as the window is not ready yet. Instantiating is delayed until even *after* `onResume()` is called in some loop.

Calling `setCurrentItem(1, false)` makes the first page the primary page, and as a result it is instantiated before the other pages, resulting in the at-first strange 1->0->2 instantiation.

**The solution?** Use a `Handler` to run the `setCurrentItem()` and load data after the other pages have been instantiated:

```
new Handler().post(new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        mViewPager.setCurrentItem(1, false);
        cleanupAndShowData();
    }
});
```

Though I'd normally want to avoid using `Handler`s, it seems this is the only option I've found thus far, because the pages themselves are added in a looper.

**EDIT**: Even the above had some issues. I ended up calling `mViewPager.setCurrentItem(1, false)` only after all pages have been instantiated (in `onPageInstantiated()`).

Answer (score 1):

```
actualPos= position%getCount();
```

If this doesn't help, please give some additional code.

I would also suggest a little modification

```
mViewPager.setOffscreenPageLimit(2);   //use 2 instead of 3 unless neccessary
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. However, the first piece of code doesn't make too much sense in terms of placement; I just used "0" instead. Also the offscreen page limit is 3 for a reason - I have exactly 3 pages that need to be shown.

Comment: The page limit is for Offscreen, so 1 visible +2 offscreen is what should be done

Comment: Perhaps you are right, but the examples I've seen use 3 (i.e., http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12538861/what-is-the-practical-effect-of-viewpager-setoffscreenpagelimit3). I'll test it out and let you know.