# Android - Sherlock content gone after 3 swipe

Tags: android, android-fragments, actionbarsherlock, fragment

I used sherlock to have action bar in android 2.3, everythings is ok but the problem is:

I have 4 tabs, after doing some works on fisrt tab if I go to the second and third tab when I came back to first tab the contetnt is ok but when I go to the last tab and then came back to the first, the conent of first fragment was restarted and everything was gone, below is my codes, why is it like that?

MainActivity:

```
public class MainActivity extends SherlockFragmentActivity implements
    TabListener {

private ViewPager viewPager;
private TabsPagerAdapter mAdapter;
private com.actionbarsherlock.app.ActionBar actionBar;
private String[] tabs = { "weblog", "news", "image", "web" };

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {        
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);  
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    viewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.pager);
    actionBar = getSupportActionBar();
    actionBar.setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(false);  
    actionBar.setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(false);
    mAdapter = new TabsPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());
    actionBar.setHomeButtonEnabled(false);
    viewPager.setAdapter(mAdapter);
    actionBar.setNavigationMode(ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_TABS);

    actionBar.addTab(actionBar.newTab().setText(tabs[0])
            .setTabListener(this), false);
    actionBar.addTab(actionBar.newTab().setText(tabs[1])
            .setTabListener(this), false);
    actionBar.addTab(actionBar.newTab().setText(tabs[2])
            .setTabListener(this), false);
    actionBar.addTab(actionBar.newTab().setText(tabs[3])
            .setTabListener(this), true);

    viewPager.setOnPageChangeListener(new ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener() {

        @Override
        public void onPageSelected(int position) {
            actionBar.setSelectedNavigationItem(position);
        }

        @Override
        public void onPageScrolled(int arg0, float arg1, int arg2) {
        }

        @Override
        public void onPageScrollStateChanged(int arg0) {
        }
    });
}

@Override
public void onTabSelected(com.actionbarsherlock.app.ActionBar.Tab tab,
        android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransaction ft) {
    viewPager.setCurrentItem(tab.getPosition());
}

@Override
public void onTabUnselected(com.actionbarsherlock.app.ActionBar.Tab tab,
        android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransaction ft) {
}

@Override
public void onTabReselected(com.actionbarsherlock.app.ActionBar.Tab tab,
        android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransaction ft) {
}
}
```

TabsPagerAdapter:

```
public class TabsPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {

public TabsPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
    super(fm);
}

@Override
public Fragment getItem(int index) {

    switch (index) {
    case 0:
        return new Blog();
    case 1:
        return new News();
    case 2:
        return new Image();
    case 3:
        return new Search();
    }

    return null;
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    return 4;
}

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The ViewPager typically only keeps a few fragments in an "idle" state and recreates the other fragments as a performance optimization. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12538927/1025599).

To override this behavior, you can call `setOffscreenPageLimit`

```
// keep 3 tabs in memory on either side of the current tab
viewPager.setOffscreenPageLimit(3);
```

Comment: exactly what I need, tnx